# In AIML how to detect user repeat words like KUKI AI?

Tags: chatbot, aiml

How to make my bot detect repeat words like kuki ai? Here is the screenshot [kuki ai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI9Ja.png)

What rule should i write to make this thing happen??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kuki's developer here. The key here is that I have a control bot which checks for things like duplicate input, whether the user is copying what Kuki says and other things like that. The control bot then either passes the input to Kuki using the `<sraix>` tag if everything is okay, otherwise it comments about repetition etc without Kuki having to get involved.

The first part of my control bot category looks like this (user repetition and copying parts have been deliberately removed:

```
<category>
<pattern>*</pattern>
<template>
    <think><set name="userinput"><input/></set></think>
    <condition name="userinput">
        <li><value><input index="2"/></value>(user has repeated themselves)</li>
        <li><value><get name="kukiresponse"/></value>(user is copying Kuki)</li>
        <li><sraix><bot><bot name="(kuki main bot)"></bot></bot><input/></sraix></li>
    </condition>
```

So the user says something to the control bot which activates the * category. It sets a predicate called "userinput" with the contents of the user's input. I then check userinput against what the user just said and also if it matches what Kuki just said. If both parts are clear, the input is passed to Kuki.

Hope that explains it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'm actually building chatbot in programab but the problem is it doesn't supports sraix tag so is there any way to do it without using sraix tag or without making a control bot? Can we do this within the main bot?

Comment: Yes. You could prefix every pattern in your bot with something like MAINBOT eg MAINBOT WHAT IS YOUR NAME and then instead of my 3rd li tag, do a srai out to MAINBOT <input/> instead. That way, everything the user says will hit the * category, as it's unlikely the user will say MAINBOT HELLO